# How to pass the entity id to the unique validation in a Form Request on Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have the following route defined:

```
Route::put('/{organisationId}', 'OrganisationController@update');
```

And I have the following `FormRequest` for the update request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Organisation;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateOrganisationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'required|min:3|max:60|unique:organisations,name,' . $this->get('organisationId')
        ];
    }
}
```

And I am trying to use it like this in my controller:

```
public function update($organisationId, UpdateOrganisationRequest $request)
{
    $organisation = $this->organisationRepository->byId($organisationId);

    if (!$organisation) {
        return $this->error('Organisation not found.', $this::Bad_Request);
    }

    $this->organisationRepository->update($organisation, $request->validated());

    return $this->success(
        fractal($organisation, new OrganisationTransformer())
    );
}
```

This appears to trigger the unique validation error, because it doesn't appear to exclude the id I am trying to update.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

---

Before using `FormRequest`, this is how I implemented the same functionality above and it was working fine:

https://pastebin.com/raw/CDEg6qLt

I was able to update the same organisation with the same name and the unique validation rule didn't trigger an Validation exception.

Comment: Doesn't your single rule need a `key` that corresponds to a field name?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the question. I am trying to use https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique validation rule. I am trying to tell the rule what record id to ignore this rule on by getting the `organisationId` from the route url. This is what I was doing before https://pastebin.com/raw/zTtAUcy0 and it was working fine. It stopped working when I implemented separate `FormRequest` to do the validation.

Comment: That's exactly my point. In `rules` method, according to your old method of validation, it should be `return [ 'name' => 'required....`.

Comment: Oh... I see the error in my copy & paste. Let me update it and give it a go.

Comment: Okay, it was my mistake. The functionality is now working as intended.

Comment: @revo Please post your comment as answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rules defined in a `FormRequest`'s `rules` method should be in form of a key / value pair that corresponds to an input name and it's validation rule respectively. You missed `key` here so chances are validator looks for a field named `0` that doesn't exist.

Add name and test result:

```
return [ 'name' => '....' ];
```